# How to create the metamodel for multiple persistence units using the same entity classes?

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I get:
    diagnostic error: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type

for:

```
                            <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml -Aeclipselink.persistenceunits=com.mysimpatico_MemoPlatform-database_nbm_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU,com.mysimpatico_inmemory_persistence_nbm_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU</compilerArguments>
```

I'm trying to have both a temporary (in-memory) and a permanent db, with the same schema.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458742/why-the-compiler-doesnt-recognize-the-metamodel-attributes) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the project with the previous configuration, i.e. with only one persistence unit to generate the metamodel classes. Then add the 2nd persitence unit to the persistence.xml and the following to the pom.xml:

```
<compilerArguments>  -Aeclipselink.persistenceunit=com.mysimpatico_MemoPlatform-database_nbm_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU </compilerArguments> (the name of 1 persistenceunit)
```