# Has eclipselink JPA2 Criteria API pom.xml configuration been simplified?

Tags: maven, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, pom.xml

From my pom   http://code.google.com/p/memorizeasy/source/browse/MemoPlatform/persistence/pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
              <!-- Without this, the annotation processor complains about persistence.xml not being present and fail -->
                            <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml -Aeclipselink.persistenceunits=com.mysimpatico_MemoPlatform-database_nbm_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU</compilerArguments>
              <!-- For an unknown reason, the annotation processor is not discovered, have to list it explicitly -->
                            <processors>
                                <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**We discussed this last year [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458742/why-the-compiler-doesnt-recognize-the-metamodel-attributes), and reported a relevant [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328560) (no one cared about @eclipselink).**

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385092/eclipselink-2-5-metamodel-generation-using-maven?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm the author of the plugin.

To make configuration a lot simpler I would recommend you test: https://github.com/ethlo/eclipselink-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With EclipseLink 2.2.0, it works for me without specifying the processor. The compiler argument is still needed.

Comment: so do you still use maven-processor-plugin? Would you post your pom.xml configuration?